# Can ajax communicate calls of functions between two clients?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

**Question**

- Is it possible to communicate events or javascript simply through ajax/xhr?
- And if so, *how* asynchronous/synchronous would this be?

**Context**

- I'm attempting to build a basic pong multiplayer webapp based around javascript/jquery. I thought about how I could synchronize movement between the players on both clients and decided that I wanted to keep  it as much client-side as possible. Played around with some ideas, (it was as bad as me thinking about using txt files with 3 boolean values and a user id being called for every single game) but I really couldn't think of any better way short of using some kind of js backend engine. (which i really do *not* want to do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use WebSocket (HTML5) for that. Most of the modern browsers support it.

http://slides.html5rocks.com/#web-sockets

More Info: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Fun fact: Stackoverflow uses WebSocket too! *ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com*

Example of using WebSocket in multiplayer games:

- http://browserquest.mozilla.org/
- http://rawkets.com/
- http://jfd.github.com/wpilot/
- [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&q=WebSocket+games)

Comment: Aren't web sockets still a client/server communication tool rather than a client/client communication tool?

Comment: That is why I always see "NetworkError: 502 Server Hangup - http://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/" in Firebug. lol

Comment: @nnnnnn - Yes and the other client requests for the data and the server can send it data easily.

Comment: hmmn, web sockets are great and all but I was hoping to be able to run this on ie8 hahaha but i'll give you merit to your answer but yeah a clean client-client solution would be great

Comment: also, I don't want to have to host another server

Comment: Decided to accept this after realising that i ended up using websockets for this in the end haha, cheers for the great answer :)